# How to use the absolute path in the head

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to get the absoulte path in the head of html?

I want to use for the absoulte path a variable. I did not find anything for this case. Is something like this possible?

```
 <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="{absolutePATH}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

...
<body> 
<script> var absolutePATH = windows.location.href;</script>
```

I don´t know how can I put the var in the head. Normally we can use **document.write**...But in the head? There is no value, or id in the link tag.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need absolute path anymore, `/` will do the trick

```
   <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: If I am in localhost. this works. But if I deploy th application on server it does not work anymore

Comment: which backend language did you write it ? (php,ruby, python blah blah )?

Comment: Frontend javaScript/Angular2 Backend Spring Boot

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-pattern-comparison

Answer (score 1):

You can use a slash (`/`) to references the root directory.

```
  <head>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
```

Here a list as quick reference:

```
   /   = Root directory
   .   = This location
   ..  = Up a directory
   ./  = Current directory
   ../ = Parent of current directory
   ../../ = Two directories backwards
```

If you need a client side solution in ES6 you can use this code:

```
  var path = window.location.href,
      sourceNode = document.createElement('link');
  sourceNode.rel = "stylesheet"; 
  sourceNode.href(`${path}/css/bootstrap.min.css`);
  document.head.appendChild(sourceNode);
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. I have to use the absolute path

Comment: @trap do you render your HTML page at server side using for example PHP, or you want a client solution means only JS code?

Comment: I have for my backend a Spring boot application, for the client side web application  I am using Angular2

Comment: @trap have you tried to look at documentation for Spring, in this case just output in your HTML the <link> tag with the right absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

You can load this CSS manually:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var absolutePath = window.location.href;

      var link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = "stylesheet";
      link.href = absolutePath + "/css/bootstrap.min.css";
      document.head.appendChild(link);
    </script>
  </head>
```

Note that it will create an element targeting `/css/bootstrap.min.css` file, relative to the **current page**.

For example, if you execute this code at this page, it will try to load `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993155/how-to-use-the-absolute-path-in-the-head/38993218/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

If you want to load it using absolute path from web-site root, then simply use `/css/bootstrap.min.css` URL.